# facebook application users wall post

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

```
I like to post data from application to many users who have granted the application.
I tried in following steps.

step:1 first get access_token as an application by following.
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?    
client_id=XXXXXX&client_secret=YYYYYYYYYYYY&grant_type=client_credentials

step2:
    $facebook = new Facebook("KEY","SECRETKEY");
    $param  =   array(
      'method' => 'stream.publish',
      'message' => 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
      'target_id' => 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ',
      'attachment' => $attachment,
      'access_token' => GENERETED ACCESS TOKEN FROM STEP1 ,
      'callback'    => ''
    );

    $fqlResult2 = $facebook->api("/IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII/feed/" , "post", $param);

but the application cant post to the targeted users wall how can i achieve?
The error was "User not visible".

but works for the code given below:[retrieve user info]
$fql    =   "select name, hometown_location, sex, pic_square, email from user where    
            uid=1000000001";
$param  =   array(
   'method'     => 'fql.query',
    'query'     => $fql,
    'access_token' =>GENERETED ACCESS TOKEN FROM STEP1 ,
  'callback'    => ''
);

$fqlResult2   =   $facebook->api($param);

so how can application can post the specified users wall/newsfeed?the above code was wrong?
```

Comment: I got ,no problem, but now, appliation can post to the users wall who grant that application but when application posted to the users wall then recepient`s name and picture were displayed but I want to show different fanpage`s Logo and custom title

Comment: how can i replace that logo and title

Answer (score 0):

The error "user not visible" means the user's privacy settings prevent you from posting on their wall.

Also, you're using the old REST API which has been deprecated. You should be using the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

Comment: user's privacy settings allow but (#210) User not visible errors